# time comparison in two editText : android

Tags: android, time

I have two editText in which i enter the time in and time out. I googled but couldn't find a proper answer for comparing two editText having time in them. i want to create a kind of validation function which tells that time in cannot be less than time out.
for eg if i come office at 09:00 AM i cannot leave office at 8:AM

my time picker function for one editText is :

```
 {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                    int minute) {
                                // Display Selected time in textbox
                                txtTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                tpd.show();


            }
```

Comment: convert time in millis and find out difference.

Comment: can u pls explain how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public boolean TimeValidator(String time1, String time2) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        boolean b = false;
        try {
            java.util.Date ArrTime = sdf.parse(time1);
            java.util.Date DepTime = sdf.parse(time2);

             // Function to check whether a time is after an another time
            b = DepTime.after(ArrTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Provide values of editTexts in the function parameters. As there has been ".after" method 
used in this snippet, another one - ".before" can be used as well.

Check like this :

```
if(Timevalidator(et1.getText().toString(), et2.getText().toString())
{
// DO something
}
else
{
// DO something
}
```

Comment: i have provided value but how to compare like if(Timevalidator(et1.getText().toString() > et2.getText().toString())

Comment: .after and .before . should they be used to compare?

Comment: Works perfectly... Great answer

Comment: sorry m new took me time to understand

Comment: It's fine. Digging yourself helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this in this code there are two functions time_In and time_out that will be called on time picker view for respective timepicker view of in and out time.

let me know if you have any concern

```
public void time_In()
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute)
            {

                String minutes = "";

                startTimeHour = selectedHour;
                startTimeMinute = selectedMinute;

                if (selectedMinute < 10)
                {
                    minutes = "0" + selectedMinute;
                }
                else
                {
                    minutes = String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                }

                if (selectedHour > 12)
                {
                    selectedHour -= 12;

                    timeSet_in = "PM";
                    edt_time_in.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet_in.toString());
                    selectedHour += 12;

                }
                else if (selectedHour == 0)
                {

                    selectedHour += 12;

                    timeSet_in = "AM";
                    edt_time_in.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet_in.toString());
                    selectedHour -= 12;
                }
                else if (selectedHour == 12)
                {

                    timeSet_in = "PM";
                    edt_time_in.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet_in.toString());
                }
                else
                {

                    timeSet_in = "AM";
                    edt_time_in.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet_in.toString());
                }

                arriveLoadHour = selectedHour;
                arriveLoadMinute = selectedMinute;

            }
        }, hour, minute, true);// Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }

    public void time_Out()
    {

        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(InformationActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute)
            {
                String minutes = "";
                if (selectedMinute < 10)
                {
                    minutes = "0" + selectedMinute;
                }
                else
                {
                    minutes = String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                }
              //timeSet_in is the TIME IN that will compare the time with time out from timepicker view
              //arriveLoadHour is the time in and selected hour is the time out
                if (timeSet_in.equals("AM"))
                {
                    if (arriveLoadHour == 12)
                    {
                        if (selectedHour > 12)
                        {

                            selectedHour -= 12;

                            timeSet = "PM";
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            timeSet = "AM";
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    else if (selectedHour > 12)
                    {
                        selectedHour -= 12;
                        timeSet = "PM";
                        edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());

                    }
                    else if (selectedHour == 0)
                    {
                        selectedHour += 12;
                        timeSet = "AM";
                        edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                    }
                    else if (selectedHour > arriveLoadHour)
                    {

                        if (selectedHour == 12)
                        {

                            timeSet = "PM";
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            timeSet = "AM";
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("", "Time IN Equals AM..TIME OUT" + arriveLoadHour);

                }
                else if (timeSet_in.equals("PM"))
                {

                    Log.e("", "Arriveeeee" + arriveLoadHour);
                    if ((selectedHour == 0) && (selectedMinute == 0))
                    {
                        selectedHour += 12;
                        timeSet = "AM";
                        edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());

                    }

                    else if (arriveLoadHour == 12)
                    {

                        if (selectedHour < 12)
                        {

                            Utilities.showToast(InformationActivity.this, "Finish time cannot be before start time");

                        }

                        else
                        {

                            timeSet = "PM";
                            selectedHour -= 12;
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }

                    }
                    else if (arriveLoadHour > 12)
                    {

                        Log.e("", "ARRIVED" + arriveLoadHour);
                        if (selectedHour < arriveLoadHour)
                        {
                            Utilities.showToast(InformationActivity.this, "Finish time cannot be before start time");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            timeSet = "PM";
                            selectedHour -= 12;
                            edt_time_out.setText(selectedHour + ":" + minutes + " " + timeSet.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);

        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();
    }
```

Comment: i guess your code would also work just fine. but i have already implemented the above code. thanks a lot for answering. got some concepts cleared by your answer